# How to prove an inequality

Tags: inequality, induction, provability

$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are rational numbers and all $> 0$.

$\max \left\{\dfrac{a}{b} , \dfrac{c}{d}\right\} \geq \dfrac{a+c}{b+d}\geq \min 
\left\{\dfrac{a}{b} , \dfrac{c}{d}\right\}$

Hope someone can help me with this one. How would you go on proving the validity? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (+1) This is a very useful inequality that I have used many times. To be a bit more general, it only requires that $b$ and $d$ have the same sign.

Comment: It is true for real numbers $a, b, c, d$, not just for rational...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{a+c}{b+d}-\frac ab=\frac{b(a+c)-a(b+d)}{(b+d)b}=\frac{bc-ad}{b(b+d)}$$

Similarly, $$\frac{a+c}{b+d}-\frac cd=\cdots=\frac{ad-bc}{(b+d)d}$$

Observe that the signs of the terms are opposite as $a,b,c,d>0$

Comment: And this is the proof that shows we only need $b$ and $d$ to have the same sign (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=\min\{a/b,c/d\}$. This means that 
$$ m \le \frac ab \qquad \text{and} \qquad m\le \frac cd,$$
which is equivalent to $bm\le a$ and $dm\le c$. Thus we get
$$a+c\ge bm+dm=(b+d)m$$
which is equivalent to 
$$\frac{a+c}{b+d}\ge m.$$

The proof of the inequality for maximum is similar.

(Note that in all steps, where we multiplied the inequality by some number, this number was positive. Therefore the sing of the inequality was not changed.)